# Is there a way for a display-buffer-base-action function to know the forthcoming major-mode?

Tags: buffers, window, major-mode

I am writing a mode that implements a persistent horizontal window (very similar to the "persistence compile window" in ECB).  While I did study the ECB code it is quite old and endeavored to work with even more ancient verions of emacs.  I am trying to write code the makes use of the many recent enhancements to emacs' windowing system.

It would appear that display-buffer-base-action is exactly the point in display-buffer's processing sequence to hook in my window management smarts.  I am able to classify newly created buffers base on buffer-name (e.g. *Completions*) and on whether of not they are related to a live process (using comint-check-proc).  What I cannot do is classify a newly created buffer base on its ultimate major-mode.  This is because when display-buffer is called on a newly created buffer that buffer's major-mode has not yet been set.

Is there any way to "peer into the future" to determine what major-mode will later get established?

Comment: The following link contains a complex example using a custom function attached to the `display-buffer-alist` that examines a buffer after its creation with `find-file-noselect`, and then displays the buffer differently based upon various criteria:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame

Comment: If the O.P. is able to provide additional details regarding how and when the major-mode is determined, the forum participants may be able to be of more assistance -- even if we don't use ECB. :)  There may not necessarily be a **good reason** to limit the answer to using the `display-buffer-base-action`, when an appropriate function (with conditions) attached to the `display-buffer-alist` would likely suffice -- it can even be `let`-bound so as to avoid unintended side effects.

Comment: Just fix that mode's code instead and you've got one headache less to worry about.

Comment: @lawlist: I took a look at the example. It is no more functional than my current code as it is entirely based on examining the name of the buffer. Nor is display-buffer-alist an obvious solution since it is processed during display-buffer and hence has access to no additional context.

Comment: @wasamasa: Not a helpful suggestion.  The very reason for writing the window manager is explicitly not to have to modify other code.

Comment: I do consider this as a bug because the majority of buffers displayed comes with the right mode enabled and I've been able to fix the few ones were this wasn't the case.

Comment: You will likely need to spend some time gathering a list of those rare exceptions where major-modes are not set until after the `display-buffer` family of functions run their course, and then go about devising a system to deal with it -- e.g., examining the value of `this-command` / `last-command`, examining the active buffer, creating a list of known functions that cause problem, adding appropriate entries into the `auto-mode-alist`, and modifying the source of the problematic functions as wasamasa suggested.